# Can the 'suggested' tags show one less (leads to a weird clickjacking thing)?

Tags: feature-request, edits, asking-questions, tag-autocomplete

When I type a tag faster than the server can AJAX back some suggestions, I try and hit "save edits" or similar and I will accidentally click on the bottom suggestion in the autocomplete list (it pops down in front of my cursor when I click).

This just lead me to an incorrect tagging of a question (since fixed).

If it shows one less, maybe this won't happen?

Or perhaps it is too infrequent, and the benefit of having an extra one outweighs the accidentally selecting of the bottom one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely *not* like seeing the suggestion list reduced to 4 tags high, unless there were more suggestions put into a 2nd or even 3rd column (giving 8 or 12 suggestions, respectively).

Moreover, there are two solutions to the problem already (and they aren't mutually exclusive):

1. Slow down, and make sure what you're about to save is correct
2. Aim for the bottom part of the Save Edits button, since 2/3rds of it is still visible with the suggestion dropdown visible

I've made many, *many* edits and I've never had this problem, even in the beginning. I usually end up saving the edits with the dropdown expanded (using solution #2) since it's an extra click to get it to hide.

Of course, if you use the 10k inline tag editor, the save button isn't visible at all, and there is already a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54491/move-the-save-tag-edits-button-so-its-never-covered-by-the-tag-suggestion-drop) to get that changed.

Comment: Thanks, this is some useful information.